# .xyz domain not recognized by apache2 as valid hostname

Tags: virtualhost, apache2

When I try to add a virtual host of my new domain name that ends with .xyz, apache tells me that it can't resolve the hostname :

```
[Wed Jan 26 21:31:53.994125 2022] [core:error] [pid 25525] (EAI 5)No 
address associated with hostname: AH00547: Could not resolve host name 
saleori.xyz -- ignoring!
```

Is there a solution for this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: IIRC that is normally only a warning and not a fatal error, so your web server will start.  Apache does a basic sanity check and alerts you as the operator when it suspects that you made a configuration error/typo and a hostname that doesn't work is an easy check. That may not be an error though, you can set up a site before the hostname becomes active. To completely remove the warning. Ensure that the domain *can* be resolved. Get your DNS working, or simply add an entry to the hosts file on the webserver. But saleori.xyz won't resolve for me either.

Comment: @Bob after some hours it seems to work! It was certainly a DNS problem... Thanks!